# Do adjunctions map to every object in a category?

Tags: category-theory

I am trying to show that right adjoints preserve limits. So suppose we have $F: C \rightarrow D$ and $G: D \rightarrow C$ be 2 adjoint functors with $G$ the right adjoint. So suppose we have a limit $(N, \phi)$ of the diagram $F: C \rightarrow D$ where $\phi$ is indexed by objects $X$ in $C$ with $\phi_X: N \rightarrow F(X).$ Now I want to show that $(G(N), G(\phi))$ is a limit of $G: D \rightarrow C.$ However, something that confuses me is that $G(\phi_X): G(N) \rightarrow G(F(X))$ are the morphisms but can this be indexed by every object in $D?$ The family of morphisms for a cone for the object $G(N)$ should be $\psi: G(N) \rightarrow G(Y)$ for every object $Y$ in $D.$ So does $F(X)$ hit every object in $D?$ That is, for every object $Y$ in $D$ does there exist $X$ in $C$ such that $F(X) = Y?$

Do we need every object to be hit?

Comment: An easy counterexample is to take practically any reflective subcategory. The abelianization functor on the category of groups is definitely not surjective (or essentially surjective).

Comment: In most basic examples of adjunction, you can see that the answer is no, e.g. in most (but not all) free/forgetful adjunctions for algebras, the answer is no

Comment: @MaliceVidrine The abelianization functor *is* essentially surjective, and in fact any reflector to a full subcategory is, since $\epsilon_X: FGX\to X$ Is an isomorphism.

Comment: @ArnaudD. It seems rather clear that Malice was talking about the one of the two adjoints in that adjunction which is not surjective.

Comment: Regarding the post itself, you've misinterpreted the claim. We rarely take limits of large diagrams, and $C,D$ will usually be large in talking adjunctions. The limit of $F$ will just be the initial object of $D$ if $C$ (and thus $D$) has one, but right adjoints need not preserve initial objects. The problem is again that an initial object may be expressed as a *large* limit, but right adjoints preserve only limits indexed by small categories. So take a small $J$ with a functor $u:J\to D$ and show $G$ preserves the limit of $u$ if it exists.

Comment: In @ArnaudD's defense, I did phrase that in a maximally confusing way.